# How to set Timer for individual session variable in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-5, redis

In my recent there is a situation where I retrieve a session data and I want to show the data suppose for 5 minutes after that it will kill the session. Is there any way I can set timer for each session variable in Laravel?

Answer (score 0):

In the `config/session.php`, set the lifetime of the session.

```
'lifetime' => 5,
```

Also, comment out this field in `php.ini` to allow garbage collector to clean the expired session

```
session.gc_maxlifetime
```

Comment: I think this is for the overall session timer.If I have a particular session variable and I want to set a time for that and after certain time it'll kill the session with that time.